# Can I directly import a .sql file into a XAMPP installation

Tags: java, xampp, mysql

I am packaging a java webapp software using XAMPP so that my users do not have to install dependencies like mysql. I can run the webapp.

I copied over the schema files (.frm) format to the xampp mysql/data directory.
But I have a mysqldump file that I want to ship with the software so that on the first installation the tables are created and some default data is populated. Can you suggest a good way to do that?

My understanding is that the .frm files contain only the schema.
The best solution for my usecase would be to package the .sql file with the software so that it gets run for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I have a script that the user must run when using the software for the first time. In that script I import the .sql file using `mysql -u <username> -p<password> <database-name> < file.sql`.